# How to delete an image that has been set as the background image of a picture box in C#

Tags: c#

I have a C# win form application that sets a new image = to an image from a file. Like this:

```
var displayPicture = Image.fromFile(/*path*/);
PicBoxPictureDisplay.BackgroundImage = displayPicture;
```

But when I go to delete it with:

```
File.Delete(/*path*/);
```

I get: "The process cannot access the file [name of file used in .FromFile]

How can I delete the .FromFile image?

Edit: the following methods fail;

1. PicBoxPictureDisplay.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
2. PicBoxPictureDisplay.BackgroundImage = null;
3. displayPicture.Dispose();

Comment: before deleting file, you should dispose displayPicture object

Comment: Could you please explain your action (why you want to that)?

Comment: You should remove it as the background in the picture box and explicitly remove the reference to it (dispose the object holding the image).

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev I have tried displayPicture.Dispose(); Still fails.

Comment: @SeM I want to delete the image that I set for displayImage

Comment: @RickvandenBosch  I have tried PicBoxPictureDisplay.backgroundImage = null; and displayPicture.Dispose(); Still fails

Comment: set PicBoxPictureDisplay.BackgroundImage=null, and then try to delete the image using File.Delete("filepath"),

Comment: @JacobGarner It would be nice if you add this kind of info beforehand next time, so other users don't take time to answer your question with stuff you already tried.

Comment: @JacobGarner The file or stream must be available for the duration of the Image instance, so you need to load your image then create new object and clone/copy it to new one. Then you wiill be allowed to delete.

Comment: Have a look at [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and check which process is _actually_ locking your file. Maybe you also have some other process targetting the file (for instance if you just placed it there with a completely separate application?)

Comment: @RickvandenBosch I only have the image being used in the win form app. The file is in the Bin/Debug folder.

Answer (score 0):

as already mention you need to dispose the object. Specifically you need to call `Dispose()` on the `BackgroundImage`:

```
PicBoxPictureDisplay.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
System.IO.File.Delete("test.png");
```

this way the lock on the file will be realsed and you can delete it.

Setting `PicBoxPictureDisplay.BackgroundImage = null;` will not help because it does not remove the object from memory, that you once loaded. It will only remove the reference to it. The lock will still remain.

Comment: I tried that, Still fails.

Comment: then the problem is not cause by the code that you have posted. Because using your posted code, my solution works. I just tested it. Any other process that is using this file? do you use it anywhere else as a background image?

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of.

Comment: The only thing that I find different is that I use this to get the file path: public string GetFilePath(string fileName)
        {
            string path = "";

            var pathToReturn = new FileInfo(fileName);
            path = pathToReturn.FullName;

            return path;
        }